# i need to extract particular data or information from email body, in uipath

Tags: email, automation, uipath

in attached screenshot, I need to extract data of - short-description from email body using UI-path.

I tried different regex method, but didn't work because the length of the string value in short-description may change every time

Answer (score 1):

You need to Get Email messages first and save that as a variable
Then use a For Each Item activity.
In the properties change the `Type Argument` to `System.Net.Mail.MailMessage`

Then you can get the body by using Log Message and typing
`item.body.tostring`.

For Each Property:

[image: For Each Property]